# Get ApplicationUser object without going to database in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I have a .Net 4.5 ASP.Net website based on Webforms. This website uses the latest security framework of OWIN and ASP.Net Identity to sign in a user.

Once the user is signed in, I can see an authentication cookie in Chrome dev tools Application tab. I need to get the *ApplicationUser* object in code-behind of an aspx page by using this authentication cookie. I have tried some code as below, but it creates the ApplicationUser object by reading from some tables in database.

**Question**

How can I get the *ApplicationUser* object for currently logged in user in code-behind of aspx page without making a database trip?

**Code I have tried**

```
UserManager manager = new UserManager();
var loginInfo = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo();
ApplicationUser appUser = manager.FindByName("abc xyz");//database call
```

**Code I have used to login user**

```
///login the user using OWIN framework (not forms authentication)
var manager = new UserManager();
ApplicationUser appUser = new ApplicationUser();
appUser.Email = user.Email;
appUser.UserName = user.DisplayName;
appUser.EmailConfirmed = true;
appUser.Id = user.UserId;
appUser.PicUrl = user.Userpic;


IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, appUser, false);//creates the asp.net identity cookie
IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);//redirects to the protected url
```